# Who decides which VFX studio will work on a movie?

Tags: production

I am a visual effects student and I am curious to know who must be deciding the choice of VFX studio in a movie. Because each studio (when talking about big movies) has its own specialty. For example Weta Digital has developed it's own [tissue system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4KYk7LhSSw). Some studios specialise in dynamics.

I think it must be decided on the basis of the demand of the story. But who actually decides? Director? Producer? Someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately everything gets decided by the director. Assuming that the director is wise enough to make those decisions as per the budget. Now thats his job!! to make the best and feasible decisions for making the vision most beautiful and creative as possible. If he lacks knowledge on VFX technologies he can appoint a [VFX creative director](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFX_creative_director).

> The VFX creative director is a position common in films, television
>   programs, and computer games using a large amount of visual effects.
>
> For movies which are fully or partly computer generated, a VFX
>   creative director works closely with the director. On smaller
>   VFX-intensive productions such as music videos or some television
>   commercials, a VFX creative director may also assume the
>   responsibilities of the director. They are charged with making
>   creative and aesthetic choices for visual effects. Although the role
>   is generally more creative in nature, most VFX creative directors have
>   a technical background and may exert a strong practical hand in
>   production.
>
> **Responsibilities**
>
> The responsibilities of a VFX creative director are very much like
>   those of an art director, production designer, or chief creative
>   officer, though with a particular focus on the computer-generated
>   imagery of their projects. They are primarily responsible for
>   directing and supervising the creative and technical execution of
>   visual effects sequences, from concept to completion, including:
>
> ```
> Set extensions and matte painting
> Bluescreening
> Digital animation
> Digital effects
> Compositing
> ```
>
> The VFX creative director may delegate responsibilities to visual
>   effects supervisors, visual effects editors, film compositors,
>   rotoscope artists, matte painters, and 3D animators.
>
> VFX creative directors may therefore have input on various aspects of
>   production, including:
>
> ```
> Story development and storyboarding
> Blocking, staging, locations
> Advising the director on actor movement
> Cinematography
> Costume, makeup, and props, particularly when there are special effects considerations
> ```

courtesy: Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

The director is the one to decide. He have a vision of a movie and how he "see" the picture. Based on demo reels he decide which studio use. He can decide that some parts of the movie make one studio and other (like explosions) is done by another.

Of course, the producers (or whoever is giving money and have and impact on movie making) can make or force his own. Then what happen is the common struggle between director and money. Sometimes directors will walk away from making a movie when they don't see how their vision could be created with the resources he is provided.